# Redux store not updating component view on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having trouble with the view not rendering after state change to the store.

I can see with the logging middleware that the actions are called properly and that the store's state has the new values. If I navigate to another page with react-router, then come back, the users are properly displayed from the store, so I know that `mapStateToProps` is working.

**MyComponent**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        users: state.users.all
    };
};

const actionCreators = {
    fetchUsers
};

export class Users extends React.Component<UsersProps, UsersState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {           
            // initial values
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsers();
    }

    render() {
        // return PrimeReact DataTable with users prop
    }
}

export default compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators),
    injectIntl,
)(Users);
```

**Actions**

```
export function fetchUsers() {
    return async dispatch => {
        const users = await new UserService().users();
        return dispatch(receiveUsers(users));
    };
}

function receiveUsers(users: User[]) {
    return { users, type: RECEIVE_USERS };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export default combineReducers({
    users
});

function users(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                all: action.users,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Store**

```
export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
    const middlewares = [
        loggerMiddleware,
        thunkMiddleware,
    ];
    const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

    const store = createStore(reducer, middlewareEnhancer);

    return store;
}
```

Comment: does your component had a shouldComponentUpdate method?

Comment: Not currently, but I've tried adding it and returning true but no luck with that.

Comment: What does your component look like?  What environment are you in (DOM or Native)?

Comment: I'll update the component in the OP, but it's in DOM

Comment: Are you updating an array?

Comment: I'm not manipulating it directly, only in the reducer I take what was received from the api call and set it in the state.

Comment: Updating arrays are always tricky. You should either use forceUpdate (not recommended) or return new object from your reducer. Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893279/updating-object-within-redux-state-array-not-re-rendering-react-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is ok. Upgrading the `react-dom` npm dependency from `16.4.2` to `16.7.0` fixed the issue.